# Tinder like onclick swiping on the same container with angular animations

Tags: html, angular, animation

I have a card. There are 2 buttons . Just like tinder users can swipe right and left using those buttons . I have been using angular animation and plain html for this . I am confused how to do both animations at same container.

Currently with the provided code the card goes right and comes back on both clicks. I want it to be 2 different directions on 2 different button clicks.

## TS

```js
animations: [
    trigger(
      'swipe', [
        transition(':enter', [
          style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0},),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1}))
        ]),
        transition(':leave', [
          style({transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1}),
          animate('500ms', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0}))
        ])
      ]
    )
```

## HTML

```html
 <div class="card-cover">

                  <div class="main-card" *ngIf="tinder" [@swipe]>
                    <div class="main-card-content">
                      <p>Do You Deploy Commercial-Grade Antivirus And Firewalls Across Your Network?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="class-footer-content">
                      <div class="covering-ad">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="first-card-shadow card-shadow"></div>
                  <div class="second-card-shadow card-shadow"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="action-buttons">
                  <button (click)="tinder = !tinder">yes</button>
                  <button (click)="tinder = !tinder">no</button>

                </div>
</div>
```

I am searching around for a result. New to angular animations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed something like this and I've built a proof of concept you can see it on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tinder-swipe). the design was taken from [here](https://codepen.io/julessmiles/pen/yJqQKK)

Put your keyframes in another file

```
import { keyframes, style,animate } from '@angular/animations';

export const swiperight = [
  style({ opacity: 1 }),
  style({ transform: 'translate3d(200%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 120deg)', opacity: 0 }),
]

export const swipeleft = [
  style({ opacity: 1 }),
  style({ transform: 'translate3d(-200%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -120deg)', opacity: 0 }),
]
```

This is how you import your animations

```
import * as kf from './keyframes';
```

And register them with the component

```
  animations: [
    trigger('cardAnimator', [
      transition('* => swiperight', animate(750, keyframes(kf.swiperight))),
      transition('* => swipeleft', animate(750, keyframes(kf.swipeleft)))
    ])
  ]
```

This video explains [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Z2C0wy4bmg)